The index of the commutator subgroup in a $p$-group
Let $G$ be a $p$-group of order greater than $p$. Prove that the index of the commutator subgroup $G'$ in $G$ is at least $p^2$.
I understand that I need to prove that the commutator subgroup $G'$ is neither equal to $G$, nor has order $\frac{|G|}{p}$, nor is it $p^n$. However, I am unsure how to continue from this point. Could someone provide further guidance on how to proceed with the proof?

$G=G'$ is impossible for a nontrivial $p$-group, because it is solvable.

I don't have this knowledge yet.

No.
I'm supposed to solve this question based on properties of normality and Silo theorems only.

The answer is given in this post (duplicate):
Regarding the nilpotency class of finite p-groups
$G/[G,G]$ must have order at least $p^{2}$. To see this, consider any normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, such that $N$ has index $p^{2}$ (as we are in a p-group with order at least $p^{2}$ we know such a subgroup must exist). Then $G/N$ is a group of order $p^{2}$ and so must be abelian, and hence $[G,G] \leq N $. It follows that
$|G/[G,G]| \geq p^{2}$.

How does Sylow 1 give you a normal subgroup of index $p^2$?
